# Why removing other sprite after collision not working in Flame?

Tags: flutter, flame

I have two sprites in the game e.g Player and Enemy. After collision detection why `remove(Component)` method is not working?

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/geometry.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(GameWidget(
    game: CGame(),
  ));
}

class CGame extends FlameGame with HasCollidables {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    add(Enemy());
    add(Player());

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}

class Enemy extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef, HasHitboxes, Collidable {
  Enemy() : super(priority: 1);

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('crate.png');
    size = Vector2(100, 100);
    position = Vector2(200, gameRef.size.y / 3 * 2);
    anchor = Anchor.center;
    addHitbox(HitboxRectangle());

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}

class Player extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef, HasHitboxes, Collidable {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('player.png');
    size = Vector2(100, 100);
    position = Vector2(0, gameRef.size.y / 3 * 2);
    anchor = Anchor.center;
    addHitbox(HitboxRectangle());

    return super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    position += Vector2(1, 0);
  }

  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, Collidable other) {
    if (other is Enemy) {
      print('Player hit the Enemy!');

      remove(Enemy());  //<== Why this line is not working?
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to remove a new instance of an enemy component, you have to remove the specific one that you collided with, which in this case is `other`.
You also want to remove `other` from the game where it is added, if you do `remove` on the component you are trying to remove a subcomponent.

```dart
  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, Collidable other) {
    if (other is Enemy) {
      other.removeFromParent();
      // It can also be done like this since you have the `HasGameRef` mixin
      // gameRef.remove(other);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh it is related to OOP. Thank you Lukas.